# One Calendar correlating with event colors

Tags: calendar

I was hoping someone could help me to figure out how to essentially use one calendar, and have the drop down (choice) categories configure with a color. So if I am scheduling an event, I would select "Add" on the calendar, have the form display, use a category drop down and if I select Room A, for instance, I select it from the drop down category, and upon Saving the event, it will show on the calendar as purple. Room B will show up as Red. Is this possible?

I understand that you can overlay, and have four overlaid calendars, but these have been criticized for lacking ease of use. I am trying to avoid having my staff have to click into a certain calendar and then post the event, **but rather have one calendar to work from that correlates with different colors.**

Please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: The maximum number of overlays is actually 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overlays all within the same list, instead of multiple lists/calendars. Create each view filtered and add them each as an overlay. When the user clicks New, they'll select Room A or Room B, and then the overlays will still work.

Important to keep in mind the root calendar view, the one at the bottom of the overlays, needs to filter out the events in the other views.

More details: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/